# How to iterate thru a folder and get filetype as a resoult in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm new in Python and also here. I am trying to find an answer how to get a list of files and folders with file type recognition in a perticular folder. I found a solution [here](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic) but it fails when a folder appears. Here is the code I wrote:

```
import re, magic, os

incoming_dir = '.'
files = os.listdir(incoming_dir)
for f in files:
  print magic.from_file(f, mime = True)
```

Is it a way to ignore folders using python-magic library? If not, any better solution? I'm using linux OS.

Answer (score 1):

This prints out the dir name if not a dir then prints its mime type and file name

```
>>> import os, magic
>>> incoming_dir = '.'
>>> m = magic.open(magic.MAGIC_NONE)
>>> m.load()
>>> files = os.listdir(incoming_dir)
>>> for file in files:
...     if os.path.isfile(file):
...             print "Name:{0} Type:{1}".format(file, m.file(file))
...     elif os.path.isdir(file):
...             print "Name:{0} Type:Dir".format(file)
```